# Caching lookup values in an e-commerce website

Tags: c#, cache, static, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an e-commerce website. I have a `CarMake` dropdown which contains car make names and their corresponding Id, for example: { 1:Alfa romeo }, { 2:Audi }, { 3:BMW }, etc

I want to keep this lookup in cache, so I won't have to make a trip to DB every time I want to get the corresponding Name or Id...

So in my infrastructure layer, I read the data from DB and keep it in cache, I am using a static `CarMakeLookup` class:

```
public static class CarMakeLookup
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<short, string> _carMakeIdLookup;
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, short> _carMakeNameLookup;

    static CarMakeLookup()
    {
        _carMakeIdLookup = new Dictionary<short, string>();
        _carMakeNameLookup = new Dictionary<string, short>();

        using (var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
        {
            DropdownRepository dropdownRepository = new DropdownRepository(context);

            var carMakes = dropdownRepository.GetCarMakes();
            foreach (var carMake in carMakes)
            {
                _carMakeIdLookup[carMake.CarMakeId] = carMake.CarMakeName;
                _carMakeNameLookup[carMake.CarMakeName.ToLower()] = carMake.CarMakeId;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetCarMakeName(short carMakeId)
    {
        if (carMakeId <= 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (_carMakeIdLookup.ContainsKey(carMakeId))
        {
            return _carMakeIdLookup[carMakeId];
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public static short GetCarMakeId(string carMakeName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(carMakeName))
        {
            string lowerCaseCarMakeName = carMakeName.ToLower();
            if (_carMakeNameLookup.ContainsKey(lowerCaseCarMakeName))
            {
                return _carMakeNameLookup[lowerCaseCarMakeName];
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static Dictionary<short, string> GetCarMakeLookup()
    {
        return _carMakeIdLookup;
    }
}
```

I also need to display car make in a dropdown in my View... so I need a `List<SelectListItem>` to be displayed as a dropdown. So in my Application layer I have another static class which holds this list:

```
public static class CarCache
{
    static CarCache()
    {
        var selectCarMake = new SelectListItem { Value = "-1", Text = "Select a car", Disabled = true, Selected = true };
        CarMakeItemsIncludingSelect = new List<SelectListItem>(); // Dropdown's first option should be "select a car"
        CarMakeItemsIncludingSelect.Insert(0, selectCarMake);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<short, string> carMakeKeyPair in CarMakeLookup.GetCarMakeLookup())
        {
            var selectListItem = new SelectListItem { Value = carMakeKeyPair.Key.ToString(), Text = carMakeKeyPair.Value };
            CarMakeItemsIncludingSelect.Add(selectListItem);
        }
    }

    public static List<SelectListItem> CarMakeItemsIncludingSelect { get; private set; }

    public static string GetCarMakeName(short carMakeId)
    {
        return CarMakeLookup.GetCarMakeName(carMakeId);
    }

    public static short GetCarMakeId(string carMakeName)
    {
        return CarMakeLookup.GetCarMakeId(carMakeName);
    }
}
```

I have a few more dropdowns like this in my application, for example `HouseType`, `JobType`, etc

Everything works fine, the only problem is that my application startup time is slow... I assume one problem is that when I start debugging the application, the application starts building all these static cache classes, and since these classes are static I cannot inject the `DbContext` into them... so each dropdown should build its own `DdContext` instance, get corresponding data from DB and Dispose of `DbContext`. There is no performance problem with the production server...

Any recommendation on how to improve this cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global static state makes your code untestable...

I would define your car make lookup as:

```
public class CarMakeLookup
{
    public CarMakeLookup(IEnumerable<(short Id, string Make)> data)
    {
        Makes = data.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d.Make);
        Ids = data.ToDictionary(d => d.Make, d => d.Id);
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<short, string> Makes { get; }
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, short> Ids { get; }
}
```

And read it with:

```
public class CarMakeReader : IReader<CarMakeLookup>
{
    public CarMakeReader(Func<ApplicationDbContext> context) => 
        Context = context;

    Func<DbContext> Context { get; }

    public Task<CarMakeLookup> ReadAsync()
    {
        using (var context = Context())
            return new CarMakeLookup(
                from cm in context.CarMakes
                select (cm.CarMakeId, cm.CarMakeName));            
    }
}
```

Where `IReader<>` is simply:

```
public interface IReader<TSet>
{
    Task<TSet> ReadAsync();
}
```

There should be also an extension method `Cache` defined nearby:

```
public static class Reader
{
    public static IReader<TSet> Cache<TSet>(this IReader<TSet> source) =>
        new CachingReader<TSet>(source);
}
```

Where:

```
class CachingReader<TSet> : IReader<TSet>
{
    public CachingReader(IReader<TSet> source) => 
        Lookup = new Lazy<Task<TSet>>(() => source.ReadAsync());

    Lazy<Task<TSet>> Lookup { get; }
    public Task<TSet> ReadAsync() => Lookup.Value;
}
```

Now register you reader in the IoC container as a decorated singleton:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(ctx => new CarMakeLookup(
    ctx.Resolve<Func<ApplicationDbContext>>())
    .Cache()).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not able to fully understand your answer... where are you caching the data? are they cached in DbContext?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I register a singleton. Will share a link to a demo repository a little bit latter today.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Here is the [Demo](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/cachingreader)...